# Merging files together at a specific time

Tags: audio, sox

As the title suggest's, I want to merge files together but I want to be able to delay the 2nd file... Can I do this with sox? or do I have to use another audio editor... if so I need a cli  (command line interface for it)

So a example...

I have a sound file that start's at 0s but then I want another sound file to start at 50s when I merge the sound files together...

I have read the docs a few times for sox and I cant fine anything about it, or if it is possible with sox...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sox 3.wav -p pad 00:00:20.5 0 | sox - -m 2.wav -p pad 00:00:10.5 0 | sox - -m 1.wav combined.wav
```

Comment: So pad delays the audio?, just read the docs it adds a silence so it kinda emulates a delay anyway... thanks....